# How to trigger automated emails from MVC application with pdf attachment the content of which is a dynamic web page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC Web application.
My requirement is to trigger automated emails daily at a specific time with the pdf attachment. I have a custom web page, the contents of which change hour by hour. The content of This page should go into pdf attachment. This page can also have charts, grids etc.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

`My requirement is to trigger automated emails daily at a specific time`
=> Use Hangfire to schedule the task of sending emails

`The content of This page should go into pdf attachment.`
=> User iTextSharp library to generate pdf documents

Comment: If i want to set up my project on Server, should i open the web site and keep it for sure, for hangfire to send emails. Also does that mean that the sending mails will stop if by any chance the web page browser is closed?

Comment: no. the hangfire works totally on server and does not depend on the client browser whether its open or not

Comment: itextsharp and rotativa, not sure which one is good. Rotativa gives direct method for converting action to a pdf. But in some blog i read that it was not working on server. Even before that the version 1.7.4 installed from nuget is a failure, blogs are suggesting to use its pre release version , not sure if pre release versions works fine or not on server.